# Route giving error on reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, browser-history

So I have routing working with redux, but I have a problem with reloading in one of the routes.

app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store , { history } from './store';

import Connect from './components/Connect';
import PhotoList from './components/PhotoList';
import PhotoContent from './components/PhotoContent';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={Connect}>
        <IndexRoute component={PhotoList}></IndexRoute>
        <Route path="view/:id" component={PhotoContent}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/app.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "app.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

This is my code, `history = syncHistoryWithStore(store, browserHistory)`. Then I try to reload the page while inside one of the view/:id, and I get the error:

`GET http://localhost:8080/view/app.min.js`

Do you guys have any idea why this is happening?
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

I run the webpack server from command line with:

`webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot --history-api-fallback`

Comment: That's not an error. That's a normal HTTP GET

Comment: which web server are you using? you have to serve the `app.min.js` file at all urls. See [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#configuring-your-server).

Comment: I'm using `webpack-dev-server` in node. I also run it with `--history-api-fallback`, which I assume redirects to /

Comment: What is the url, right before you try to reload when you are on the `view/:id` route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `index.html` is referencing the correct bundle file.

For webpack, make sure your config uses this:

```
config.devServer = {
    ...
    contentBase: 'src',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    ...
};
```

or, if you declared it as a single object:

```
{
    ...
    devServer: {
       ...
       contentBase: 'src',
       historyApiFallback: true
    }
}
```

It will redirect your requests to `/` and have react handle it.

Run your `webpack-dev-server` like this: `./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --inline --hot`

EDIT:

While working with you over chat, I noticed that the bundle reference in your `index.html` was incorrect. Moving it to `../app.min.js` fixed it.

Comment: I always run `webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot --history-api-fallback`, so I have no idea why it's not working

Comment: Try adding your webpack config to your question. The more code we see the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: Added webpack config

Comment: Nothing in your config points to port `9090`, are you sure this is the port webpack dev server uses? Try to go through the default port `8080`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo I made, the server is running on `localhost:8080`, and the URL before reload is `localhost:8080/view/AAAAAAA`

Comment: Try adding the `devServer` section to your `webpack.config.js` (as suggested) and change your start script to `./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --inline --hot` instead.

Comment: The only other suggestion I have is to remove the `context` key on your config. You should not need it in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114877/discussion-between-mario-tacke-and-parkicism).

Comment: Hey Mario, I just have one more question You have `/src/index.html/` and `/dist/bundle.js`, how come in `index.html` you do `<script src="../bundle.js">` and not `src="../dist/bundle.js`?

Comment: That is because index.html is part of dist.